# How do i make seeder from this type of database [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make seeder based on this create method and database,

Here is my creating method in Controller

**ItemController.php**

```
public function create(Request $request){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $statement = DB::select("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'items'");
        $nextId = $statement[0]->Auto_increment;
        $image = $request->file('item_image');
        $fileName = "item_image_".$nextId.".".$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path  = $request->file('item_image')->move('storage/image/',$fileName);
        $imagepath = 'storage/image/'.$fileName;

       $item = Item::create([
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'image_url' => $imagepath,
            'item_name' => $request->item_name,
            'item_description' => $request->item_desc,
        ]);


       return response()->json($item,201);
    }
```

**ItemSeeder.php**

```
public function run()
    {
        //
        for($i = 1;$i <= 10;$i++){

            \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('items')->insert([
                'image_url' => '',
                'item_name' => '',
                'item_description' => '',
                'user_id' => '',
            ]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, seeders are best used in scenarios which require static information. Given that your data is dynamically generated, please look into the use of factories: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database-testing namely sections, writing factories and using factories.

Comment: In addition to the above, guessing the next auto increment is incorrect. Don't do that. Save the record, get the ID and then save the image.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks for the suggestion, will do that.

Comment: @Mysteryos so in my case, it isn't applicable? or it's just not a good application?